# Convert R sum() and order() syntax to Python

Tags: python, r, sorting, vector, syntax

I'm working on porting an R function to Python, but I've gotten hung up on a section because I can't figure out how certain operations behave. The part giving me the most trouble is:

```
if (RANKSTAT==1) {
FDR <- (cumsum(post.H0[order(post.H0)]) / (1:length(post.H0)))
FNR <- rev(cumsum((1-post.H0)[order(1-post.H0)])) / (Nb.Cell - 1:length(post.H0))
Se <- cumsum((1-post.H0)[order(post.H0)]) / (sum(1-post.H0))
Sp <- rev(cumsum(post.H0[order(1-post.H0)])) / (Nb.Cell - sum(1-post.H0))
}

if (RANKSTAT==2) {
FDR <- (cumsum(post.H0[order(LB,decreasing=TRUE)]) / (1:length(post.H0)))
FNR <- rev(cumsum((1-post.H0)[order(1-LB,decreasing=TRUE)])) / (Nb.Cell - 1:length(post.H0))
Se <- cumsum((1-post.H0)[order(LB,decreasing=TRUE)]) / (sum(1-post.H0))
Sp <- rev(cumsum(post.H0[order(1-LB,decreasing=TRUE)])) / (Nb.Cell - sum(1-post.H0))
}
```

Note that `post.H0` and `LB` are vectors in R. What is happening in `sum(1-post.H0)` and how can I replicate it in python?

Another difficult aspect is the `order` function. As far as I know, Python's sorting can't take a vector, so what is `order` doing internally that I can duplicate? The R documentation wasn't very clear so I still don't understand the nuances of the function.

The entire script I'm porting is [Here](https://github.com/cran/PhViD/blob/master/R/BCPNN.R)

Much obliged for any help you can give. Please comment if there's a piece of information I left out that would be useful for solving this.

Cheers!

Comment: A general tip: if you want to port R code to Python, you should use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).  Numpy provides datatypes that are much more similar to R's than Python's builtin lists and the like.

Comment: Yes, I'm using numpy data types where possible, and also for most math functions.